# Interpretation of $R^2$ in simple regression

Tags: r-squared

I have run a linear regression with five independent variables and two dependent variable I am using EPS and ROE as my dependent variable and Board meeting, Board size, leadership, Independend Non-Executive, Audit committee as my Independent variable and my resulting Model is shown as:

```
Model Summary 1    (Dv: ROE)

R. Square 0.39
Adjusted R-Square = 0.014
Error of the Estimate = 19.4807565
a. Predictors: (Constant), Board meeting, Board size, leadership, 
     Independent Non-Executive, Audit committee. 

Model Summary 2    (Dv: EPS)
R   .308a           
R Square = .095
Adjusted R Square = .072
Std. Error of the Estimate = 35.308797
a. Predictors: (Constant), Board meeting, Board size, leadership, 
     Independent Non-Executive, Audit committee
```

I got confused regarding how to explain the correlation of my independent and dependent variables. I'm also wondering if my results are any good.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both model 1 and model 2 seem to be poor as the adjusted $R^2$ indicates that less than $10\%$ of the variance is explained by the model.  The first model looks like it fits ROE better than the second one fits EPS  but the adjusted $R^2$ is small $(1.4\%)$ even though the $R^2$ is $39\%$.  There is probably overfitting in that case.

Comment: Did you notice that the two models involve *different* dependent variables? It therefore makes little sense to say one is a "better fit." Also, it's clear there is no $R^2$ equal to 39% (it couldn't possibly be consistent with an adjusted $R^2$ of just 0.014): the second line of output is likely corrupted.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that one model is predicting EPS and the other ROE.  I don't know what these dependent variables mean and how they are connected.  So you are right that I should not be comparing the model but rather only comment on the fit of the individual models.

Comment: I suspect, given the context, that EPS is earnings per share and ROE is return on equity.